# Парсинг XML

Tags: xml, android, синтаксический-анализ

Работаю на андроид с Xml. Столкнулась с тем, что мне нужно парсить xml такого вида:

```
<name>
<![CDATA[ Пример]]>
</name>
```

Понимаю, как достать текст, атрибуты, а как мне достать слово "Пример"?

Comment: Открываете <name>. Проверяете: есть ли CDATA. Если есть - тогда заменяете <![CDATA[ и ]]> на пробел. И все:)

Comment: @atnartur, а можно подробнее о том, как я это должна проверить?)

Comment: Пример поиска подстроки в строке:

     String someText = "aaaaaatrollaaaaa";
     if( someText.contains("troll") ) {
        // .. someText contains substring troll :)
     }

Но, возможно, в вашем случае было-бы удобнее использовать **indexOf**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо парсить [SAX'ом](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html), простейший пример использования [здесь](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html)

Касаемо секции `CDATA` ее надо ловить в хэндлере `DefaultHandler.characters()`, причем с конкатенацией, поскольку он может вызываться несколько раз.

**P.S.** [[@atnartur](/users/8212/atnartur)](/users/8212/atnartur) неправ, поскольку парсер вернет без `<!CDATA[]>`, вернет только `Пример`

Comment: @Barmaley Не права @Мария_1 . Я только прочитал и описал пример выполнения задачи, который я выполнял на php. Действительно - строка возвращалась без CDATA. Я не знаю ничего о написании приложений к андроид.

Answer (score 1):

Простой пример Serializing with CDATA blocks 
http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php